# Password changing view is not working correctly

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to see if user matches their old password, if they don't then it will give a message saying "Your old password in incorrect" but if they match their old password then it should check if user matched new and confirmed password correctly, if they did not then it should give a message saying "Your new passwords do not match", But even when I match the old password correctly it always says "Your old password is incorrect" even if it is correct.

views.py

```
@login_required
def userchange(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username, password=request.POST['Old password'])
        if User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username, password=request.POST['Old password']).exists():
            if request.POST['New password1'] == request.POST['New password2']:
                User.objects.update_or_create(username=request.user.username, password=request.POST['New password2'])
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your password has been changed succesfully!'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your new passwords do not match'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/change.html', {'error':'Your old password is incorrect'})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'main/change.html')
```

change.html

```
<h1>Note: You will be logged out</h1>
<h2>{{ error }}</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="password" placeholder="Old password" name="Old password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="New password" name="New password1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" name="New password1">
    <button type="submit">Change password</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why there are two `name="New password1">` in from?

Comment: Here you assign  `request.POST['New password2']` So in form it's `New password2`.

Comment: I have fixed it. The result is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are not stored as plain text in the database so `User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username, password=request.POST['Old password'])` will not work (Also you already have the user from request.user why filter). Try using `check_password` instead. Also use `set_password` to set new password:

```
user = request.user
old_password = request.POST['Old password']
new_password1 = request.POST['New password1']
new_password2 = request.POST['New password2']
if user.check_password(old_password):
    if new_password1 == new_password2:
        user.set_password(new_password1)
        # rest of code
```

Also as an alternative try to use the built in view for changing password [PasswordChangeView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView).

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem most likely is that the below code is always evaluating false no matter what you put:

```
if User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username, password=request.POST['Old password']).exists():
```

It would be better to break it up and first get the the user object, then compare the current user.oldpassword with the request.POST['Old_password'].
Not sure how your model looks like for user but something like the below may work:

```
User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
if User.Old_Password == request.POST['old password']:
    #add your code and finish if statement
```

Something like the above might work for yourself.